# Reshape Dataframe pandas with merge cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'key': ['value1','value2','value1','value2'],
'domain': ['domain1.com','domain1.com','domain2.com','domain2.com'],
'url' :['urlB','urlA','url1','url2'],
'score' : [12,14,200,2001]})
```

I'd like to get result 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQt1W.jpg)

I've tried with transpose, stack... but can not get the same.

I'm new to Python Pandas, 
Please advice

[Edit]

Thanks @jezrael for the response, it works by using

```
df = df.set_index(['key','domain']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Move to the next level, for sorting,
I started from the beginning for adding more rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['value1','value2','value1','value2','value2','value3'],
    'domain': ['domain1.com','domain1.com','domain2.com','domain2.com','domain3.com','domain4.com'],
    'url' :['urlB','urlA','url1','url2','url3','url4'],
    'score' : [12,14,200,2001,10,5]
})

dfdomains = pd.DataFrame({
    'domain': ['domain1.com','domain2.com', 'domain3.com','domain4.com'],
    'order' : [3,1,2,4]
})
```

I get dataframe by your answer:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['key','domain']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
```

That gave me the result:

```
domain  domain4.com domain3.com domain2.com domain1.com
url score   url score   url score   url score
key                             
value1  NaN NaN NaN NaN url1    200.0   urlB    12.0
value2  NaN NaN url3    10.0    url2    2001.0  urlA    14.0
value3  url4    5.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I'd like to `sort df1` by `order of dfdomains`: that means the first columns of `df1` is `domain2.com (order= 1)`

Expecting: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKQsF.jpg)

Can you please advice @jezrael
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.set_index(['key','domain']).unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)

domain domain1.com       domain2.com      
             score   url       score   url
key                                       
value1          12  urlB         200  url1
value2          14  urlA        2001  url2
```

1. First[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex`
2. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape,
3. Then [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) in `MultiIndex` in columns
4. Last sort them by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

EDIT: First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for ordering by column `order` and then add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - is necessary all values of `order` has to be in `df['domain']`

```
order = dfdomains.sort_values('order')['domain']
print (order)
1    domain2.com
2    domain3.com
0    domain1.com
3    domain4.com
Name: domain, dtype: object

df1 = (df.set_index(['key','domain'])
         .unstack()
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
         .reindex(order, axis=1, level=0))
print (df1)
domain domain2.com         domain3.com       domain1.com       domain4.com  \
               url   score         url score         url score         url   
key                                                                          
value1        url1   200.0         NaN   NaN        urlB  12.0         NaN   
value2        url2  2001.0        url3  10.0        urlA  14.0         NaN   
value3         NaN     NaN         NaN   NaN         NaN   NaN        url4   

domain        
       score  
key           
value1   NaN  
value2   NaN  
value3   5.0
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for the sample given. But in fact, my data is bigger than that, so I encounter error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" for unstack function, please advice

Comment: Hi jezrael, I've figured out with df.set_index(['key','domain'], append=True), can you tell me is there a way to sort columns (domain1.com, domain2.com) by score? I appreciate

Comment: @xuke - Can you explain more? Do you think sorting by `sum` of `score` like in sample first score is `26` and second `2201`, so if sorting order is not changed?

Comment: I've edited my question for details, please help, thanks

Comment: sorry for border you again, how can we iterate the df1.groupby('keyword').first()? thanks